# Facebook Graph API - determine if user liked a wall post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a small button in an Android app that lets the user like a wall post. I would like it to show if the user has already liked the post so the user knows that it's worked. The API here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
shows how to add and delete a like for a particular post but there doesn't seem to be a way to query the like state. 
Calling:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/19292868552_10150189643478553

seems like the obvious solution but this gives a parser error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want this: https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553/likes ... or did i misunderstand?

Comment: I found that later but I want to avoid searching through all the likes for the current user. I guess there is no way in Facebook though.

Answer (score 1):

There IS actually a solution for this. You have to use FQL. Here, this is what will work

select user_id from like where object_id=your object_id AND user_id=me()

If the result returns an empty array, then the user never liked the post, if it returns a result, the user has liked the post. Simple :)

Comment: This does not always work.  I've written a simple iOS application where you can like an object based on the id.  If you like it, via my application, you can see that you liked it on the facebook website.  But then when you call that FQL query, looking for that data array, it's still empty.

Comment: It seems that the LIKE table only considers videos, notes, links, photos and albums, not posts. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/